# How to have Access show a child form which the user must interact with?

Tags: forms, ms-access

First, I'm not sure if children forms, or child form, are the correct terms for what I want, so maybe that's why I didn't find anything.

I have a main form in Access. It has buttons to open other forms. I would like to prevent the user from toggling between forms.

For example, let's say the user opens the products form from the main form. In that case, I want the user to only be able to work with product form until he closes it.

Is there a way to do this?

So far, I open them, but I can't make this "locking".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set the product form's [**Modal** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-modal-property-access):

> When a form opens as a modal window, you must close the window before you can move the focus to another object.